# Using the RxJS TestScheduler to compare multiple subscriptions to a hot observable

Tags: javascript, system.reactive, rxjs

I have the following `getPriceStream` method I want to test:

```
import Rx from 'rx';

export default class TradingService {

    constructor() {
        this.subscribedCcyStreams = {};
    }

    getPriceStream(ccyPair) {
        let existingStream = this.subscribedCcyStreams[ccyPair];

        if (existingStream)
            return existingStream;

        let newStream = Rx.Observable.create(obs => {

                // subscribe to live service here once we have one
                var ccyStream = Rx.Observable.interval(500, Rx.Scheduler.default)
                    .map(_ => this.createFakePrice(ccyPair))
                    .subscribe(obs);

                return () => {
                    ccyStream.dispose();
                    delete this.subscribedCcyStreams[ccyPair];
                };
            })
            .replay(1)
            .refCount();

        return this.subscribedCcyStreams[ccyPair] = newStream;
    }

    createFakePrice(ccyPair) {
        return {
            ccyPair: ccyPair,
            price: Math.random() + 1,
            timestamp: Date.now()
        };
    }
}
```

I want to test that the following would have the first and last subscription producing matching values (as they have the same ccy pair, and should therefore return the same hot observable), and the second should have different values.

```
tradingSvc.getPriceStream('GBPAUD').subscribe();
tradingSvc.getPriceStream('EURUSD').subscribe();
tradingSvc.getPriceStream('GBPAUD').subscribe();
```

For one subscription, I would just set the `Rx.Scheduler.default` to use my `TestScheduler`, then having something like the following to run the scheduler and record values:

```
var testScheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler();
Rx.Scheduler.default = testScheduler;
var results = testScheduler.startScheduler(
    () => tradingSvc.getPriceStream('GPBAUD'), 
    {created: 0, subscribed: 0, disposed: 10000});
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this for 3 separate calls to the one function, which would produce 2 different streams.  In Rx.NET I would have previously just subscribed normally with `.subscribe()` to the 3 calls, pushing the values of each subscription into a collection, and then controlling the shared TestScheduler incrementally via the usage of `advanceBy(x)`.  But the RxJS TestScheduler doesn't have this option, and I assume it's not the recommended way anyway.

Thoughts?

Comment: Where are you seeing that it doesn't support `advanceTo` and `advanceBy`? It derives from the `VirtualTimeScheduler` so it should have them.

Comment: Ah. A combination of not reading the source properly, and lack of decent intellisense in JS :) Thanks.